# How to bring 3d effect with transparent sphere?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I was generating small spheres inside a large big sphere with different colors. When the larger sphere has more opacity value (see second last line) then color of inside spheres not coming true. When the opacity value less the outer sphere looks like 2d circle. Anyone know how to bring more 3d effects to outer sphere such that inner spheres also show their assigned color. 
Thanks for reading. 
[image]
This image generated by these lines of code. I am generating sphere and cylinders in each separated line and connecting one graphics3d.

```
Export["Figure.png", Graphics3D[{
Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{7.62036,11.56248,52.164},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{17.4576,38.0532,52.2},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{13.452,52.3692,63.9348},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{34.2768,25.8492,71.5008},10]
,Opacity[1.], Yellow, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{38.8908,29.8668,88.7172},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{34.0704,-0.668844,96.6888},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{54.0516,-7.569,71.3712},10]
,Opacity[1.], Yellow, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{65.3052,-35.5188,56.3988},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{54.3252,-37.242,68.9064},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{61.8732,-39.8976,45.516},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{57.9312,-8.15484,68.6832},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{65.622,3.447,62.3064},10]
,Opacity[1.], Yellow, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{93.4416,20.7372,53.64},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{87.6444,10.39524,42.9588},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{66.4164,55.3968,33.324},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{27.33,47.9292,21.942},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{26.5428,18.3708,-5.7594},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-5.07372,25.5876,-25.8684},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-16.5828,7.66824,-43.8516},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-22.1808,40.062,-24.1536},10]
,Opacity[1.], Yellow, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-37.1544,79.2696,-34.7904},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-18.5208,87.486,-4.73172},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0,.50196,0], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-32.418,66.5436,4.149},10]
,Opacity[1.], Yellow, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-16.9812,69.3396,21.3084},10]
,Opacity[1.], Red, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{3.26316,74.1072,7.08348},10]
,Opacity[1.], Red, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{34.8468,55.9068,-0.0181656},10]
,Opacity[1.], Red, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{51.3312,51.3024,-17.0316},10]
,Opacity[1.], Red, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{51.4656,44.0256,-35.61},10]
,Opacity[1.], Yellow, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{58.5156,34.2936,-35.0232},10]
,Opacity[1.], Yellow, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{70.0476,17.6472,-39.1224},10]
,Opacity[1.], Red, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{45.8412,17.7864,-30.2628},10]
,Opacity[1.], Red, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{53.1468,48.4056,-31.8588},10]
,Opacity[1.], Yellow, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{66.5124,26.4552,-7.8852},10]
,Opacity[1.], Yellow, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{53.1792,37.4592,14.4132},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{16.0812,41.9652,39.738},10]
,Opacity[1.], Yellow, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{32.8692,75.2004,37.734},10]
,Opacity[1.], Yellow, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{31.6368,75.6312,83.148},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{21.8004,63.5004,52.0632},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{1.97304,60.9564,27.84},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{14.8848,49.992,36.7476},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{6.41064,73.7796,23.6976},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[ 0.60392157,0.80392157,0.19607843], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{8.50452,75.5352,16.9872},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{10.0806,41.4252,15.5412},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{5.2884,11.01288,38.7744},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-24.9276,14.64,22.1856},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-17.064,19.032,44.214},10]
,Opacity[1.], Yellow, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-31.4856,48.6132,45.7164},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-45.6444,56.706,67.9872},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-74.7876,34.4328,44.4828},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-95.1144,44.1864,30.7644},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-103.1148,23.4216,40.4952},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-77.4192,8.19684,0.197088},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-81.8856,6.49044,-10.4046},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-70.9464,-14.2968,7.10844},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-70.1112,-0.424932,31.1808},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-78.3564,-19.1832,18.6192},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-60.5808,17.9232,23.3652},10]
,Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1], Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-65.5152,8.57016,21.4932},10]
,Opacity[1.], Yellow, Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-75.5016,6.39948,21.1776},10]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{7.62036,11.56248,52.164},{17.4576,38.0532,52.2}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{17.4576,38.0532,52.2},{13.452,52.3692,63.9348}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{13.452,52.3692,63.9348},{34.2768,25.8492,71.5008}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{34.2768,25.8492,71.5008},{38.8908,29.8668,88.7172}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{38.8908,29.8668,88.7172},{34.0704,-0.668844,96.6888}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{34.0704,-0.668844,96.6888},{54.0516,-7.569,71.3712}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{54.0516,-7.569,71.3712},{65.3052,-35.5188,56.3988}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{65.3052,-35.5188,56.3988},{54.3252,-37.242,68.9064}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{54.3252,-37.242,68.9064},{61.8732,-39.8976,45.516}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{61.8732,-39.8976,45.516},{57.9312,-8.15484,68.6832}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{57.9312,-8.15484,68.6832},{65.622,3.447,62.3064}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{65.622,3.447,62.3064},{93.4416,20.7372,53.64}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{93.4416,20.7372,53.64},{87.6444,10.39524,42.9588}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{87.6444,10.39524,42.9588},{66.4164,55.3968,33.324}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{66.4164,55.3968,33.324},{27.33,47.9292,21.942}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{27.33,47.9292,21.942},{26.5428,18.3708,-5.7594}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{26.5428,18.3708,-5.7594},{-5.07372,25.5876,-25.8684}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-5.07372,25.5876,-25.8684},{-16.5828,7.66824,-43.8516}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-16.5828,7.66824,-43.8516},{-22.1808,40.062,-24.1536}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-22.1808,40.062,-24.1536},{-37.1544,79.2696,-34.7904}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-37.1544,79.2696,-34.7904},{-18.5208,87.486,-4.73172}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-18.5208,87.486,-4.73172},{-32.418,66.5436,4.149}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-32.418,66.5436,4.149},{-16.9812,69.3396,21.3084}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-16.9812,69.3396,21.3084},{3.26316,74.1072,7.08348}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{3.26316,74.1072,7.08348},{34.8468,55.9068,-0.0181656}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{34.8468,55.9068,-0.0181656},{51.3312,51.3024,-17.0316}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{51.3312,51.3024,-17.0316},{51.4656,44.0256,-35.61}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{51.4656,44.0256,-35.61},{58.5156,34.2936,-35.0232}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{58.5156,34.2936,-35.0232},{70.0476,17.6472,-39.1224}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{70.0476,17.6472,-39.1224},{45.8412,17.7864,-30.2628}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{45.8412,17.7864,-30.2628},{53.1468,48.4056,-31.8588}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{53.1468,48.4056,-31.8588},{66.5124,26.4552,-7.8852}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{66.5124,26.4552,-7.8852},{53.1792,37.4592,14.4132}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{53.1792,37.4592,14.4132},{16.0812,41.9652,39.738}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{16.0812,41.9652,39.738},{32.8692,75.2004,37.734}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{32.8692,75.2004,37.734},{31.6368,75.6312,83.148}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{31.6368,75.6312,83.148},{21.8004,63.5004,52.0632}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{21.8004,63.5004,52.0632},{1.97304,60.9564,27.84}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{1.97304,60.9564,27.84},{14.8848,49.992,36.7476}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{14.8848,49.992,36.7476},{6.41064,73.7796,23.6976}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{6.41064,73.7796,23.6976},{8.50452,75.5352,16.9872}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{8.50452,75.5352,16.9872},{10.0806,41.4252,15.5412}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{10.0806,41.4252,15.5412},{5.2884,11.01288,38.7744}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{5.2884,11.01288,38.7744},{-24.9276,14.64,22.1856}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-24.9276,14.64,22.1856},{-17.064,19.032,44.214}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-17.064,19.032,44.214},{-31.4856,48.6132,45.7164}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-31.4856,48.6132,45.7164},{-45.6444,56.706,67.9872}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-45.6444,56.706,67.9872},{-74.7876,34.4328,44.4828}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-74.7876,34.4328,44.4828},{-95.1144,44.1864,30.7644}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-95.1144,44.1864,30.7644},{-103.1148,23.4216,40.4952}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-103.1148,23.4216,40.4952},{-77.4192,8.19684,0.197088}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-77.4192,8.19684,0.197088},{-81.8856,6.49044,-10.4046}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-81.8856,6.49044,-10.4046},{-70.9464,-14.2968,7.10844}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-70.9464,-14.2968,7.10844},{-70.1112,-0.424932,31.1808}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-70.1112,-0.424932,31.1808},{-78.3564,-19.1832,18.6192}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-78.3564,-19.1832,18.6192},{-60.5808,17.9232,23.3652}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-60.5808,17.9232,23.3652},{-65.5152,8.57016,21.4932}},3]
,Opacity[1.], Black, Specularity[Black,100], Cylinder[{{-65.5152,8.57016,21.4932},{-75.5016,6.39948,21.1776}},3]
,Opacity[0.3], Gray, Specularity[White,10],Sphere[{0,0,0},140]
},Boxed->False],ImageResolution -> 600,"CompressionLevel" -> 0 ]
```

Comment: Use `Lighting->"Neutral"` to get true colors. Also in the future provide a more minimal example. People don't want to have to copy so much. Just include some of the parts.

Comment: Ok I will take care.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to add a light mesh to the sphere, if you're okay with the extra lines.

Here I used [`SphericalPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html) to create the sphere instead (I put all the other Graphics objects inside the variable `insidestuff` for easier handling):

```
Show[
 Graphics3D[{
   insidestuff
   },
  Boxed -> False,
  ImageSize -> {250, Automatic},
  Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}
  ],

 SphericalPlot3D[
  140,
  {t, 0, Pi},
  {p, 0, 2*Pi},
  PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[White, Opacity[0.3], Specularity[White, 10]],
  Mesh -> 15,
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.3]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Sphere, Default Mesh]

Here's `insidestuff`, for copying purposes:

```
insidestuff = {Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{7.62036,11.56248,52.164},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{17.4576,38.0532,52.2},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{13.452,52.3692,63.9348},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{34.2768,25.8492,71.5008},10],Opacity[1.],Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{38.8908,29.8668,88.7172},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{34.0704,-0.668844,96.6888},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{54.0516,-7.569,71.3712},10],Opacity[1.],Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{65.3052,-35.5188,56.3988},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{54.3252,-37.242,68.9064},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{61.8732,-39.8976,45.516},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{57.9312,-8.15484,68.6832},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{65.622,3.447,62.3064},10],Opacity[1.],Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{93.4416,20.7372,53.64},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{87.6444,10.39524,42.9588},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{66.4164,55.3968,33.324},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{27.33,47.9292,21.942},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{26.5428,18.3708,-5.7594},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-5.07372,25.5876,-25.8684},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-16.5828,7.66824,-43.8516},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-22.1808,40.062,-24.1536},10],Opacity[1.],Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-37.1544,79.2696,-34.7904},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-18.5208,87.486,-4.73172},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0,.50196,0],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-32.418,66.5436,4.149},10],Opacity[1.],Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-16.9812,69.3396,21.3084},10],Opacity[1.],Red,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{3.26316,74.1072,7.08348},10],Opacity[1.],Red,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{34.8468,55.9068,-0.0181656},10],Opacity[1.],Red,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{51.3312,51.3024,-17.0316},10],Opacity[1.],Red,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{51.4656,44.0256,-35.61},10],Opacity[1.],Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{58.5156,34.2936,-35.0232},10],Opacity[1.],Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{70.0476,17.6472,-39.1224},10],Opacity[1.],Red,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{45.8412,17.7864,-30.2628},10],Opacity[1.],Red,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{53.1468,48.4056,-31.8588},10],Opacity[1.],Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{66.5124,26.4552,-7.8852},10],Opacity[1.],Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{53.1792,37.4592,14.4132},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{16.0812,41.9652,39.738},10],Opacity[1.],Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{32.8692,75.2004,37.734},10],Opacity[1.],Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{31.6368,75.6312,83.148},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{21.8004,63.5004,52.0632},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{1.97304,60.9564,27.84},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{14.8848,49.992,36.7476},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{6.41064,73.7796,23.6976},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.60392157,0.80392157,0.19607843],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{8.50452,75.5352,16.9872},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{10.0806,41.4252,15.5412},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{5.2884,11.01288,38.7744},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-24.9276,14.64,22.1856},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-17.064,19.032,44.214},10],Opacity[1.],Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-31.4856,48.6132,45.7164},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-45.6444,56.706,67.9872},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-74.7876,34.4328,44.4828},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-95.1144,44.1864,30.7644},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-103.1148,23.4216,40.4952},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-77.4192,8.19684,0.197088},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-81.8856,6.49044,-10.4046},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-70.9464,-14.2968,7.10844},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-70.1112,-0.424932,31.1808},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-78.3564,-19.1832,18.6192},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-60.5808,17.9232,23.3652},10],Opacity[1.],RGBColor[0.56078431,0,1],Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-65.5152,8.57016,21.4932},10],Opacity[1.],Yellow,Specularity[White,20],Sphere[{-75.5016,6.39948,21.1776},10],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{7.62036,11.56248,52.164},{17.4576,38.0532,52.2}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{17.4576,38.0532,52.2},{13.452,52.3692,63.9348}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{13.452,52.3692,63.9348},{34.2768,25.8492,71.5008}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{34.2768,25.8492,71.5008},{38.8908,29.8668,88.7172}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{38.8908,29.8668,88.7172},{34.0704,-0.668844,96.6888}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{34.0704,-0.668844,96.6888},{54.0516,-7.569,71.3712}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{54.0516,-7.569,71.3712},{65.3052,-35.5188,56.3988}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{65.3052,-35.5188,56.3988},{54.3252,-37.242,68.9064}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{54.3252,-37.242,68.9064},{61.8732,-39.8976,45.516}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{61.8732,-39.8976,45.516},{57.9312,-8.15484,68.6832}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{57.9312,-8.15484,68.6832},{65.622,3.447,62.3064}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{65.622,3.447,62.3064},{93.4416,20.7372,53.64}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{93.4416,20.7372,53.64},{87.6444,10.39524,42.9588}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{87.6444,10.39524,42.9588},{66.4164,55.3968,33.324}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{66.4164,55.3968,33.324},{27.33,47.9292,21.942}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{27.33,47.9292,21.942},{26.5428,18.3708,-5.7594}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{26.5428,18.3708,-5.7594},{-5.07372,25.5876,-25.8684}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-5.07372,25.5876,-25.8684},{-16.5828,7.66824,-43.8516}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-16.5828,7.66824,-43.8516},{-22.1808,40.062,-24.1536}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-22.1808,40.062,-24.1536},{-37.1544,79.2696,-34.7904}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-37.1544,79.2696,-34.7904},{-18.5208,87.486,-4.73172}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-18.5208,87.486,-4.73172},{-32.418,66.5436,4.149}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-32.418,66.5436,4.149},{-16.9812,69.3396,21.3084}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-16.9812,69.3396,21.3084},{3.26316,74.1072,7.08348}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{3.26316,74.1072,7.08348},{34.8468,55.9068,-0.0181656}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{34.8468,55.9068,-0.0181656},{51.3312,51.3024,-17.0316}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{51.3312,51.3024,-17.0316},{51.4656,44.0256,-35.61}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{51.4656,44.0256,-35.61},{58.5156,34.2936,-35.0232}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{58.5156,34.2936,-35.0232},{70.0476,17.6472,-39.1224}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{70.0476,17.6472,-39.1224},{45.8412,17.7864,-30.2628}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{45.8412,17.7864,-30.2628},{53.1468,48.4056,-31.8588}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{53.1468,48.4056,-31.8588},{66.5124,26.4552,-7.8852}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{66.5124,26.4552,-7.8852},{53.1792,37.4592,14.4132}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{53.1792,37.4592,14.4132},{16.0812,41.9652,39.738}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{16.0812,41.9652,39.738},{32.8692,75.2004,37.734}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{32.8692,75.2004,37.734},{31.6368,75.6312,83.148}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{31.6368,75.6312,83.148},{21.8004,63.5004,52.0632}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{21.8004,63.5004,52.0632},{1.97304,60.9564,27.84}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{1.97304,60.9564,27.84},{14.8848,49.992,36.7476}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{14.8848,49.992,36.7476},{6.41064,73.7796,23.6976}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{6.41064,73.7796,23.6976},{8.50452,75.5352,16.9872}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{8.50452,75.5352,16.9872},{10.0806,41.4252,15.5412}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{10.0806,41.4252,15.5412},{5.2884,11.01288,38.7744}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{5.2884,11.01288,38.7744},{-24.9276,14.64,22.1856}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-24.9276,14.64,22.1856},{-17.064,19.032,44.214}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-17.064,19.032,44.214},{-31.4856,48.6132,45.7164}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-31.4856,48.6132,45.7164},{-45.6444,56.706,67.9872}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-45.6444,56.706,67.9872},{-74.7876,34.4328,44.4828}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-74.7876,34.4328,44.4828},{-95.1144,44.1864,30.7644}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-95.1144,44.1864,30.7644},{-103.1148,23.4216,40.4952}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-103.1148,23.4216,40.4952},{-77.4192,8.19684,0.197088}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-77.4192,8.19684,0.197088},{-81.8856,6.49044,-10.4046}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-81.8856,6.49044,-10.4046},{-70.9464,-14.2968,7.10844}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-70.9464,-14.2968,7.10844},{-70.1112,-0.424932,31.1808}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-70.1112,-0.424932,31.1808},{-78.3564,-19.1832,18.6192}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-78.3564,-19.1832,18.6192},{-60.5808,17.9232,23.3652}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-60.5808,17.9232,23.3652},{-65.5152,8.57016,21.4932}},3],Opacity[1.],Black,Specularity[Black,100],Cylinder[{{-65.5152,8.57016,21.4932},{-75.5016,6.39948,21.1776}},3]};
```

Just for fun, here are some examples with different values for `Mesh`:

[image: Sphere, Other Meshes]

Comment: Looks good. Thanks a lot. Is there any other possibility without mesh lines?

Answer (score 4):

One can assume that the outer transparent shell looks more opaque near its edges. You can simulate this behavior using independent directional lighting source, which comes from the "camera" position.

In order to emphasize colors of the inner stuff, you can use different transparency for the inside and outside side of the outer shell.

```
insidestuff=Uncompress@"1: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";


Graphics3D[{{Lighting -> "Neutral", insidestuff}, 
   {Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, ImageScaled[{0, 0, 1}]}}, 
   White, FaceForm[Opacity[0.2], Opacity[0.5]], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 140]}}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]