# Improve export resolution of a 3D arrow

Tags: graphics3d

Here's a pretty red arrow:

```
arrow = Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[.25], Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, .04]]} ]
Export[StringJoin[NotebookDirectory[], "arrow.pdf"], arrow]
```

[image: zoomedOutRedArrow]

As you can see, I exported it as a pdf, so it is vectorized [*].  So because its a pdf, I should be able to zoom in a lot, right? Unfortunately for me, the answer is no:

[image: zoomed in red arrow]

Look at all those pixels! Please, **how can I make it so that this arrow can be zoomed in upon really close? What about the box line right next to it?**

Edit:
I'm trying to get the mesh from [this 3D spherical plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160273/22432) to work better also. I assume that what fixes the arrow will fix the mesh also. Let me know if I should expand this question.

Edit 2: [Looks like the answer is here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1546/22432) Does that make this a duplicate?

[*] I can't upload vector graphics here, so I took a screen shot. I assure that it looks just as crappy in inkscape. Also, I tried SVG - same issue.

Comment: At least on macos, one can do the following: Right-click on the displayed graphic in the notebook and select "Print Graphic...". In the opening print dialog, go to "PDF" in the lower left corner and select "Save as PDF". Et voilà: The resulting pdf contains a vector graphic. It still contains some not so nice artifacts... (I opened it in inkscape and was able to edit it.) @halirutan might also be interested.

Answer (score 5):

I know of no built-in method for exporting 3D plots to vector graphics. However, I found some Mathematica code for a self-written vector renderer with Lambert shading in the deeps of my hard drive. I tried to adapt it to use as few specialized functions as possible; this is why I redirect a certain task (finding neigboring triangles of edges in a two-dimensional simplicial complex ) to the [IGraph/M package](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs).

```
Needs["IGraphM`"];

cCross3 = With[{},
   Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}, {Y, _Real, 1}},
    {
     -X[[3]] Y[[2]] + X[[2]] Y[[3]], 
      X[[3]] Y[[1]] - X[[1]] Y[[3]], 
     -X[[2]] Y[[1]] + X[[1]] Y[[2]]
    },
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
    Parallelization -> True
    ]
   ];

ClearAll[VectorRenderer]
VectorRenderer[M_MeshRegion, OptionsPattern[{
    "Position" -> {0, 0, -10},
    "LookAt" -> {0, 0, 0},
    "Sky" -> {0, 1, 0},
    "LightSource" -> {6, 4, -10},
    "EdgeThickness" -> 0.0005,
    "EdgeColor" -> Automatic,
    "AmbientLight" -> 0.3,
    "Color" -> Lighter@RGBColor[0.0745, 0.176, 0.415],
    "Background" -> None
    }]] :=
 Module[{meanfun,
   eye, direction, ambient, lightsource,
   w, u, v, pts, triangles, trianglepts, trianglemidpts, 
   visibletriangles, triangledistances,
   in, out, p1, p2, p3, trianglenormals, cosα, cosθ, 
   lambertintensities, intensities, cols, p, newp, visiblecolors,
   edges, edgepts, edgemidpts, edgeneightriangles, visibleedges, 
   edgedistances, edgeintensities, edgecols, visibleedgescols,
   ordering
   },
  eye = N@OptionValue["Position"];
  direction = N@OptionValue["LookAt"] - eye;
  ambient = N@OptionValue["AmbientLight"];
  lightsource = N@OptionValue["LightSource"];

  meanfun = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, Mean[x],
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True
    ];
  w = Normalize[direction];
  v = Normalize[N[OptionValue["Sky"]]];
  u = Cross[w, v];
  pts = MeshCoordinates[M];
  triangles = Developer`ToPackedArray[MeshCells[M, 2][[All, 1]]];
  trianglepts = Partition[pts[[Flatten[triangles]]], 3];
  trianglemidpts = meanfun[trianglepts];
  visibletriangles = Range[Length[triangles]];
  triangledistances = Sqrt[Total[Subtract[
       trianglemidpts[[visibletriangles]],
       ConstantArray[eye, Length[visibletriangles]]
       ]^2, {2}]];
  in = Subtract[ConstantArray[lightsource, {Length[triangles]}], trianglemidpts];
  in /= Sqrt[Total[in^2, {2}]];
  out = Subtract[ConstantArray[eye, {Length[triangles]}], trianglemidpts];
  out /= Sqrt[Total[out^2, {2}]];
  {p1, p2, p3} = Transpose[trianglepts];
  trianglenormals = cCross3[p2 - p1, p3 - p1];
  trianglenormals /= Sqrt[Total[trianglenormals^2, {2}]];
  cosθ = Total[Times[trianglenormals, in], {2}];
  cosα = Total[Times[trianglenormals, out], {2}];
  lambertintensities = Times[cosθ, Sign[cosα]];
  intensities = Ramp[ambient + (1. - ambient) lambertintensities];
  With[{colorvector = List @@ ColorConvert[OptionValue["Color"], RGBColor]},
   cols = Map[x \[Function] RGBColor @@ (x colorvector), intensities]
   ];
  p = pts - ConstantArray[eye, Length[pts]];
  newp = Times[Transpose[{p.u, p.v}] Norm[direction]/p.w];
  visiblecolors = cols[[visibletriangles]];
  edges = Developer`ToPackedArray[MeshCells[M, 1][[All, 1]]];
  edgepts = Partition[pts[[Flatten[edges]]], 2];
  edgemidpts = meanfun[edgepts];
  edgeneightriangles = Flatten[IGMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[M, 1, 2]["AdjacencyLists"]];
  visibleedges = Range[Length[edges]];
  edgedistances = Sqrt[Total[Subtract[
       edgemidpts[[visibleedges]],
       ConstantArray[eye, Length[visibleedges]]
       ]^2, {2}]];
  If[OptionValue["EdgeColor"] === Automatic,
   edgecols = RGBColor @@@ Map[
      x \[Function] Mean[DeleteCases[x, List]], 
      Partition[(List @@@ cols)[[edgeneightriangles]], 2]
      ],
   edgedistances -= 0.01;
   edgeintensities = Developer`ToPackedArray@Map[
      x \[Function] Mean[DeleteCases[x, List]], 
      Partition[intensities[[edgeneightriangles]], 2]
      ];
   With[{colorvector = 
      List @@ ColorConvert[OptionValue["EdgeColor"], RGBColor]},
    edgecols = 
     Map[x \[Function] RGBColor[x colorvector], edgeintensities]
    ];
   ];
  visibleedgescols = edgecols[[visibleedges]];
  ordering = Reverse@Ordering[Join[triangledistances, edgedistances]];

  Graphics[
   Join[
     Transpose[{
       visiblecolors,
       ConstantArray[EdgeForm[], Length[visibletriangles]],
       Polygon /@ 
        Partition[newp[[Flatten[triangles[[visibletriangles]]]]], 3]
       }],
     Transpose[{
       visibleedgescols,
       ConstantArray[Thickness[OptionValue["EdgeThickness"]], 
        Length[visibleedges]],
       Line /@ Partition[newp[[Flatten[edges[[visibleedges]]]]], 2]
       }]
     ][[ordering]],
   Background -> OptionValue["Background"]
   ]
  ]
```

The syntax for the camera is closer to POVray's than Mathematica's, though. Moreover, `VectorRenderer` assumes that all 2-dimensional `MeshCells` of the `MeshRegion` handed over to it are triangular.

You can test `VectorRenderer` on

```
M = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Triceratops"}, "MeshRegion"];
g = VectorRenderer[M, 
 "Position" -> {10, -10, 0}, 
 "Sky" -> {0, 0, 1}, 
 "LightSource" -> {5, 0, -10}];
Export["triceratops_lowres.pdf", g];
```

[image]

If you are willing to use `Subdivide` from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161331/how-to-perform-loop-subdivision-on-a-triangle-mesh-with-mathematica/161332#161332), you will realize that there is some reason that vector renderers are seldomly used for 3D images: the performance for the export (and also for the rendering in the pdf viewer) is poor and it leads to humongous output files.

```
g = VectorRenderer[Subdivide[M], 
 "Position" -> {10, -10, 0}, 
 "Sky" -> {0, 0, 1}, 
 "LightSource" -> {5, 0, -10}
];
Export["triceratops_highres.pdf", g];
```

[image]

(This is actually a conversion of the resulting pdf to png since I cannot post pdfs here.)

If you are still willing to do this, you can use `Subdivide` to produce nice sphere and tubes; maybe also the tips of arrows. An alternative is to use `ParametricPlot3D` but that one tends to produce `GraphicsComplex`es with quadrilateral faces; these have to be split into triangles before sending them to `VectorRenderer`.

Comment: You got my upvote for this, although it doesn't solve the underlying issue. What we would need is such a renderer, that takes vertex-colors, light-positions and camera of the original `Graphics3D` into account. Then, it should create a new mesh that removes background polygons and splits existing polygons, so that the color *appears* to be smooth even if only one color per polygon is used. The result should be a set of 2D polygons that represent the 3D scene and combines original 3D Frame, axes, ticks. This can then be exported to PDF or SVG to create a real vector graphics.

Comment: @halirutan Thanks. I know, I know. I tried these things several years ago for plotting low resolution polygonal surfaces for publications. But I was quite disappointed by the quality and stopped working on that. Hence, the z-buffer is quite imperfect (look at the artifacts at the horns) and occlusion is not implemented at yet, so all polygons are exported. Moreover, I draw artificial edges on top of the triangles just to hide the fact that triangles will be separated by thin white lines after pdf export. That's quite ugly.

Comment: @halirutan Fixing light and camera would be less an issue; for multiple color triangles, we merely had to find an appropriate export format. Do you know of any? Then also shading with vertex normals be done, at least approximately.

Comment: In fact, I was looking into this several times myself and was always disappointed. I basically see 2 different ways: (1) Do the 2D projection, shading, occlusion, .. yourself and create a 2D vector graphics. Then you have to struggle with how ``Charting` `` creates the ticks because without axes or frame, it won't be useful. (2) Clean up the existing Graphics3D by replacing multicolored polygons with a refined mesh and throw out background polygons. Then you could export the Graphics3D from this view position as normal and would get a vector graphics.

Comment: However, cleaning background polygons is at least not a 5min task. But option (2) is definitely less work than reimplementing a renderer. I read through several format specs and was mainly interested in SVG, but it lacks of the colored polygons-vertices. There seem to be a PDF 3D project but my feeling is that it is abandoned.

Answer (score 4):

```
arrow = Graphics3D[
   {Red, 
    Arrowheads[.25], 
    Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, .04]]},
    ImageSize -> 2000];
```

works perfectly.

[image]

Comment: That's definitely the better option!

Comment: No, it is not a better option to use an extreme resolution to fight the missing vector-graphics export. It is merely a way around this issue which, btw, doesn't start with Mathematica. It begins that famous formats like SVG don't have a way to represent polygons with different colors for each vertex. It goes on that earlier versions of Mathematica exported *all* polygons, even the ones in the background that cannot be seen. Today, we cannot even create a Graphics3D conversion tool because there is no way to access ticks anymore, etc, etc.. I would love to see a 3rd-party package solving this.

Comment: @halirutan:  So what would be your immediate solution for the question poser?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is none as long as no one steps up to implement it. I haven't downvoted your answer either, but please be aware that it is not a solution when exporting 3D graphics. You need to take care of resolution, magnification, etc to make everthing scale properly. Just create a `Plot3D` with image size 2000 and export it. Lines are much too thin and fonts are unreadable. Please don't take it as a personal critique. It is not. I know that exporting a large rasterized version is the next best thing we have to a real solution.

Comment: oh, I see. It is the junction of the arrow head and the shaft. Took me a bit

Comment: This answer doesn't work at all. When you export it, the pdf format is not improved. It just looks better in the notebook, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @axsvl77: When exporting, you can prescribe the `ImageSize` and the `ImageResolution` for most export formats that support raster graphics. For PDF, you can use `Export[StringJoin[NotebookDirectory[], "arrow.pdf"], arrow, ImageSize -> 2000]`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Agreed. Try it; you export the pdf, zoom in. It still has the staircase. The axes are much better though